# Close div by clicking outside (with 2 different divs)

Tags: javascript

In my web i did two div with message 1 for succes and the other one for error, i have been searching how to do it but when i did it, only one div closes, for example if the succes div appears i could close, but if the error div appears it doesn´t close.

Here is my code:

```
 function hideAlertInc() {
    document.getElementById("alert-inc").style.display = "none";
}

function hideAlertCo() {
    document.getElementById("alert-co").style.display = "none";
}

document.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'alert-inc') {
        hideAlertInc()
    }
}

document.onclick = function (b) {
    if (b.target.id !== 'alert-co') {
        hideAlertCo()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added `onclick` event two times. The last one is called and the previous one is overridden. Using the following should work:

```
document.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'alert-inc') {
        hideAlertInc()
    }
    if (b.target.id !== 'alert-co') {
        hideAlertCo()
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, it only  works on 1 of the div, chrome console says "function.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at hideAlertInc (function.js:49:41)
    at document.onclick (function.js:58:9)"

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')` means the element with id `alert-inc` is not found, resulting in `null`, therefore setting `null.style` gives error.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it if someone is interesting the only thing I do is change `onclick` on the second div to `onmousedown`

like this:

```
function hideAlertInc() {
    document.getElementById("alert-inc").style.display = "none";
}

function hideAlertCo() {
    document.getElementById("alert-co").style.display = "none";
}

document.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'alert-inc') {
        hideAlertInc()
    }else{
        hideAlertInc()
    }
}

document.onmouseup = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'alert-co') {
        hideAlertCo()
    }else{
        hideAlertCo()
    }
}
```

If someone know a better solution let me know.